# Snap.svg bounding box not updated on child elements after applying transform to parent g element

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dfIBv

I have two rectangles in g element on which I apply transform. GetBBox method shows same numbers after and before transform.

If I apply same transform directly on those rectangles, getBBox method shows correct measurements.

Is there any way how to get "correct" measurements of these rectangles after applying transform to parent group element?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried element.node.getBoundingClientRect() ? I think the originals are correct, its just that they are relative to the current transforms in place. I think getBoundingClientRect may take those into account.

Answer (score 0):

Ian is correct. element.node.getBoundingClientRect() shows correct measurements. Thank you :)

Comment: after transform the element should have a matrix attribute, where matrix.e is reprenting the x-offset and matrix.f the y-offset. You could also use these values to calculate the correct position of your elements.