# Snap SVG: Dragging group doesn't update elements

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

JSFiddle here:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v402nj65/)

When dragging a group of objects, the individual objects' location attributes don't seem to be getting updated.  This occurs whether I use the default drag() handler or define my own.  Even the group BBox operation doesn't seem to update.   Code:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var move = function (dx, dy, posx, posy) {
    this.attr({
        x: posx,
        y: posy
    });
    //this.transform("t" + dx + "," + dy);
};
var block = s.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
var circle = s.circle(100, 100, 50);
var group = s.g(block, circle);

//group.drag(move, function () {}, function () {});
group.drag();
//block.drag(move, function () {}, function () {});

//just a way to keep info coming w/o an interminable script
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    bbox = block.getBBox();
    block_x = block.attr("x");
    block_y = block.attr("y");
    gbbox = group.getBBox();
    console.log("block is at " + block_x + "," + block_y,
        "   Block Bbbox is at " + bbox.x + "," + bbox.y,
        "   Group Bbbox is at " + gbbox.x + "," + gbbox.y);


}, false);
```

If I define only one object (say, a rect) and leave it out of a group, and pass my own "move" function to the call to drag, and include setting the "x" and "y" attributes explicitly, then that works.  But if I include the rect in a group, then...I can't figure out how to do it, and I've tried a few ways (see the multiple commented-out lines showing things I've tried).  I need to know where the rect sub-group element ends up after the drag, or at least the BBox of the whole group.  Neither of these seem to be getting updated -- i.e. the console log I put in shows the same numbers forever, no matter where I move the object(s).

Can anyone help?

JSFiddle here:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v402nj65/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because they are two different things, so they aren't actually interchangable.

The drag handler uses transforms. A transform doesn't affect any other attributes, its just an attribute on an element (in this case the group element).

getBBox will work in its current transform space, note this may be different to the clients (eg if the svg were zoomed in/out). So they are two slightly different methods, that do different things.

Use getBoundingClientRect if you need a bounding box relative to the client window. Use getBBox if you need a bounding box in the elements current coordinate space.

Comment: Hi Ian, i have group with several elements and I need bBox of specific element after group drag is completed. But, as you said, drag transform only apply to element (group) that is dragged, bBox of group inner elements is same as before dragging group Do you have any idea what I could try to get correct bBox? Thanks

Comment: Hard to know without seeing code, see if the top function in the plugin at http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-graffle-transform helps.

Comment: Hi Ian, method from link do some kind of transformation, but it is not correct one. It produces different offset on xaxis, yaxis, depending on current zoom scale. I added code snippet at the bottom of page. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Code is using snap.svg.zpd as well, so zoom is possible. Problem is at onStopMove function. Events are fired when group is moved arround. In group is one circle(this.select('#main-inner-circle')) which does not have predefined location inside group. Im trying to get correct cx and cy of that inner circle after moving group.

```
self.onMove = function (dx, dy, ev, x, y) {
            var clientX, clientY;
            var tdx, tdy;
            if ((typeof dx == 'object') && (dx.type == 'touchmove')) {
                clientX = dx.changedTouches[0].clientX;
                clientY = dx.changedTouches[0].clientY;
                dx = clientX - this.data('ox');
                dy = clientY - this.data('oy');
            }

            var snapInvMatrix = this.transform().diffMatrix.invert();
            snapInvMatrix.e = snapInvMatrix.f = 0;
            tdx = snapInvMatrix.x(dx, dy);
            tdy = snapInvMatrix.y(dx, dy);            

            this.transform("t" + [tdx, tdy] + this.data('ot'));
        }

        self.onStartMove = function (x, y, ev) {
            if ((typeof x == 'object') && (x.type == 'touchstart')) {
                x.preventDefault();
                this.data('ox', x.changedTouches[0].clientX);
                this.data('oy', x.changedTouches[0].clientY);
            }

            this.data('ot', this.transform().local);
            if (callbacks.onStartMove) {
                callbacks.onStartMove();
            }
        }

        self.onStopMove = function () {
            var self = this.select('#main-inner-circle');
            this.data('ot', this.transform().local);
            //self.data('ot', self.transform().local);
            console.log(self.getTransformedBBox());
            console.log(this.getBBox());
            //console.log($(self.node).offset().left - $(self.node).parent().offset().left);
            var bBox = this.getBBox();
            //var x = bBox.x + $(self.node).offset().left - $(self.node).parent().offset().left + self.getBBox().width / 2;
            //var y = bBox.y + $(self.node).offset().top - $(self.node).parent().offset().top + self.getBBox().height / 2;
            model.updateElementCoordinates(index, $(this.node).attr("rel"), { x: self.getTransformedBBox().cx, y: self.getTransformedBBox().cy });

            if (callbacks.onStopMove) {
                callbacks.onStopMove();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to post this question, I'd created the JSFiddle but left out the crucial snap.svg definitions...

```
<script src="http://snapsvg.io/assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
```

...with that, then indeed the group.getBBox() method actually works. However:

Apparently, using getBBox() is incredibly slow -- much slower than just accessing a "x" attribute of something like I was doing before grouping objects.  All I know is that my code slows to a crawl if I use getBBox()  (I have a lot of objects on the screen).

Further down in the same post mentioned earier ["Get coordinates of svg group on drag with snap.svg"[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533687/snap-svg-bounding-box-not-updated-on-child-elements-after-applying-transform-to)  recommended getBoundingClientRect(), which also works fine  *AND* is fast enough!  My new, working Fiddle showing all of these methods is here: [New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uoowythr/).

So, future users: use .node.getBoundingClientRect().